# Retrieving an id from a list through iteration - Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i am new to rails so any help would be much appreciated. I am currently trying to display only the user that has been invited by a recruiter to apply for a job post. Your advise would be much appreciated - thank you

i have 4 models: user / recruiter / invite / form / advert

users[jobseeker]: a user uses a form (application form) to apply for an advert (job post)

recruiters: recruiters create adverts(jobs) and can send an invite to a user[jobseeker] to apply to an advert [job post]

## models:

```
user has_many invites
user has_many forms

recruiter has_many invites
recruiter has_many adverts

invite belongs_to a user
invite belongs_to a recruiter
invite belongs_to an advert

form belongs_to a user
form belongs_to an advert

advert belongs_to a recruiter
advert has_many forms
```

## controllers

```
class RecruitersController < ApplicationController
  def dashboard
      @invites = @recruiter.invites
  end
end
```

## views

```
recruiters / dashboard.html.erb
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>invite info</th>
      <th>jobseeker has accepted invite & has applied - view application</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @invites.each do |invite| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= invite.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></td>
        <td>
          <div>you invited 
           <b><%= link_to "#{invite.user.firstname} #{invite.user.lastname}", user_path(invite.user) %></b> 
           to apply for 
           <b><%= link_to "#{invite.advert.title}", recruiter_advert_path(invite.recruiter, invite.advert)  %></b></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul>
          <% invite.advert.forms.each do |form| %>
              <li><%= link_to form.user.firstname, form %> form |
        applied <%= form.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

i am trying to display only the user that has been invited by the recruiter to apply for the job but instead i get all the users that have applied for the job. i tried using a ".where()" method but no luck. Your advise would be much appreciated - thank you

[image]

Comment: have you tried `@invites.where(user_id: id_of_user)` when you would have retrieved the `id_of_user` from a separate query, alternatively you can join the tables to do a single query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better use a has-many-through relationship here. See the [document](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recruiters, through: :invitations
end
class Recruiter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :invitations
end
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :recruiter
  belongs_to :advert
end
```

By using this relationship, if you want to find all users invited by a recruiter whose id is `some_number`, you can simply do the following:

```
 @recruiter = Recruiter.find(some_number)
 @invited_users = @recuiter.users
```

If you want to find all users who are invited by that recruiter and are related to a single job, say @advert, you can try:

```
@invited_users_for_some_job = @recruiter.users.
  where(["invitations.advert_id = ?", @advert.id])
```